# Momentjs is saying a non valid date is valid

Tags: momentjs

We have an address, that according to momentjs is reporting as valid.. any thoughts?

You can see the behavior in this fiddle

```
var wrong_date = "7840 W HICKS STREET";


document.write(moment(wrong_date, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").isValid()); //returns true
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jeffbeagley/2c9urj5v/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use strick format parsing:

```
var wrong_date = "7840 W HICKS STREET";

document.write(moment(wrong_date, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", true).isValid());
```

Notice the third boolean parameter set to true.

This is a strick match on the format.

Answer (score 1):

> Moment's parser is very forgiving, and this can lead to undesired behavior. As of version 2.3.0, you may specify a boolean for the last argument to make Moment use strict parsing. Strict parsing requires that the format and input match exactly, including delimeters.

```
document.write(moment(wrong_date, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").isValid()); //returns true
document.write(moment(wrong_date, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", true).isValid()); //returns false
```

You can use both locale and strictness.

```
moment('2012-10-14', 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'fr', true);
```

Comment: Always something so easy... if I had only read the documentation. :|